Show that this Integral can only be expressed in elementary functions if at least $1$ out of $3$ variables are integer
This is the part b) of a question involving primitives (antiderivatives). The first part asks us to verify that $$\int x^m (a+bx^n)^p dx\quad(m,n,p\in\mathbb{Q})$$
Can be evaluated to $$\int(a+bt)^p t^qdt\quad(p,q\in\mathbb{Q})\tag{1}$$
And I have successfully gone through this part.
But the next question asks us that (1) can only be expressed as elementary functions if and only if one out of $p,q,p+q$ is an integer, as proved by chebyshev. And the orginal question can be found below:

My thoughts:
I think we can do repetitive Integration by Parts, using $$\int f'g dx=fg-\int fg'dx$$
As:
$$\int (a+bt)^p t^qdt= \frac{t^{q+1}}{q+1}-\int p t^{q+1} (a+bt)^{p-1} dt$$
And it seems by switching the variable function for repetitively integrating, we could conclude that if the function concerned isn't integer valued, the process would end up infinitely. But I have no idea how to put this into a formal and rigorous argument.
